# Laravel relationship mutual matching (tinder case)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm applying the relationships in Laravel and I am trying to apply them in a "I like" system, it has been easy to make the relationship one to many, but I would like to have a help in mutual matching; For a system of these, what is the best option to obtain mutual matching by passing a user as a parameter.

Users

```
|id | name        | gender |
+---+-------------+--------+
| 1 | John Kenedy | male   |
| 2 | Meresa Oslo | female |
| 3 | Mike Lanes  | male   |
```

Likes

```
|id | user_id | user_liked_id |
+---+---------+---------------+
| 1 |    1    |       2       | //matching with 2
| 2 |    1    |       3       | //likes
| 3 |    2    |       1       | //matching with 1
```

to get it would be something like:

```
User::find(1)->matches()
```

I'm not sure that I can have a collection with user model data 2

App/User.php

```
...

class User extends Authenticatable
{
   ...
     public function likes()
     {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Like');
     }

     public function matches()
     {
       ????
     }
   ...
}

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't have one to many. The above behavior is: Many-To-Many and could be realized in such a way:

table "Users_Users_liked" - create table `Users_Users_liked`, unsigned integer 'user_id', unsigned integer 'user_liked_id'.
Column `id` is extra because table `Users_Users_liked` is a  many-to-many pivot.

Then in `User` class add relations:

```
public function likesToUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'Users_Users_liked', 'user_id', 'user_liked_id');
}

public function likesFromUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'Users_Users_liked', 'user_liked_id', 'user_id');
}

public function matches()
{
    return $this->likesFromUsers()->whereIn('user_id', $this->likesToUsers->keyBy('id'));
}
```

Comment: It works perfect, really the answer I was waiting for, before you did everything I needed in a much better way, thank you very much